# Insert Record in Database Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have code which can generally insert data. I have a record list

> let s = [HrefInfo {link = "introduction", description = "Introduction"},HrefInfo {link = "introduction#about-this-tutorial", description = "About this tutorial"}]

Now I want to insert record s in a database where link will be in one column, description will be in another column.

```
module Main(main) where

import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Types
import Database.HDBC.SqlValue
import Data.Convertible.Base

type Link = [Char]
type Description = String
type HrefLinktDes = [HrefInfo]

data HrefInfo = HrefInfo { link :: Link
                     , description :: Description 
                     } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

createDB :: IO ()
createDB = do {conn <- connectSqlite3 "ld.db";
               run conn "CREATE TABLE ld (url TEXT, des TEXT)" [];
               commit conn;}

storeMany :: [[String]] -> IO ()
storeMany xs =
      do conn <- connectSqlite3 "ld.db"
         stmt <- prepare conn "INSERT INTO ld (url, des) VALUES (?,?)"
         executeMany stmt $ map (map toSql) xs
         commit conn

main = do storeMany [["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]
```

When I try to break down the record it gives me error. Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The problem is type is not same storeMany should be like storeMany :: HrefLinktDes -> IO () ... but I can't use 'map' properly.

Comment: You should put that in your question, it is not clear from that code that your problem is converting `HrefLinktDes` to `[String]`.  You should also show the declaration for your `HrefLinktDes` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531165/insert-record-in-database-haskell?noredirect=1#comment30699574_20531165):

What you'll want to do is convert your list of `HrefLinktDes` to `[[String]]` before passing it to `storeMany`.  You can do this pretty easily with:

```
hrefToList :: HrefLinktDes -> [String]
hrefToList href = [link href, description href]
```

All you're doing is extracting each piece of information into the list in a specific order.  You can also do this with pattern matching or the `RecordWildcards` extension, too, but this one is pretty straightforward.  Then simply

```
main = storeMany $ map hrefToList s
    where
        s = [HrefInfo {link = "introduction",
                       description = "Introduction"},
             HrefInfo {link = "introduction#about-this-tutorial",
                       description = "About this tutorial"}
            ]
```

Alternatively, you could write a function `storeHrefs`:

```
storeHrefs :: [HrefInfo] -> IO ()
storeHrefs hrefs = do
    conn <- connectSqlite3 "ld.db"
    stmt <- prepare conn "INSERT INTO ld (url, des) VALUES (?,?)"
    execMany stmt $ map (map toSql . hrefToList) hrefs
    commit conn

main = storeHrefs hrefs
    where
        hrefs = ...
```

(This should compile, but I haven't checked because I don't have HDBC installed)

Comment: I think, there is problem in hrefToList :: HrefLinktDes -> [String], fist it should return [[String]].
hrefToList :: HrefInfo -> [String]
hrefToList href = [link href, description href]
Above is fine for one record

Comment: That's why I use `map hrefToList` on `s`.  `map hrefToList :: [HrefLinktDes] -> [[String]]`, but `hrefToList :: HrefLinktDes -> [String]`.  That code was intended to work on only one at a time, it's generally good practice to write your code that way, where you have a function that transforms a single element, then use `map` to transform a list of elements.

Comment: hrefToList :: HrefLinktDes -> [[String]]
    hrefToList (x:xs) = [link x, description x]: hrefToList xs
    hrefToList [] = [] ... I slightly change ... anyway idea works

Comment: Your definition is functionally identical to the definition of `map`: `map f [] = []; map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs`.  If you substitute `hrefToList` for `map` and `(\href -> [link href, description href])` for `f`, you have literally the same definition.  The reason why I went with only operating on a single element was so that the function `hrefToList` can be used elsewhere if you have an instance where you only need to convert a single `HrefLinktDes`.